# How should I create a clean user-facing slug from an object?

Tags: language-agnostic

Given the fact that I am using a pre-existing comment/discussion solution that uses a unique string as a thread id, I need to create a user-facing slug from an arbitrary object for the thread id that fits the following constraints:

1. Short
2. "Pretty"
3. Human-readable
4. Does not reveal internals
5. Unique per object instance

I thought about using `{FQCN}-{id}`, but it violates #4 and, when web-encoded, #2. I also considered an md5 hash of the same, but that violates #3 (and potentially #1, depending on the definition of "short").

Since the objects do not have a standardized API (eg, there's no guarantee that they'll all have a `getTitle()` method, for example), I'm at a loss as to how to come up with a slug that fits those constraints. How would you go about creating one, and if that's not possible, what format would you use that violates as few constraints as possible?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing)

Comment: What do you mean by "human readable"?  Does it have to consist of English words, or merely be chunks of pronounceable text?

Comment: Also, are those constraints ordered from most important to least important?  If not, can you give such an ordering?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like if you're using arbitrary objects, you'll want to let the objects decide for themselves. You'd want to have a base class or perhaps an interface that would define that the objects are "sluggable". Everything you're going to have slugs for would need to implement this.

That way, you would have

`getObjectFromSlug = function ()` or `function getObjectFromSlug ()`

and

`getSlug = function ()` or `function getSlug ()`

in the interface, and each of the "sluggable" objects would be required to implement this on their own. The only issue there is that you will have to manually require them to be unique on their own.